# Overload += operator as friend function

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I read that implementing operators as friend function will be better. How to overload += operator as a friend function when I already have + operator function:

```
friend Dollar operator+(const Dollar &p1, const Dollar &p2);
friend Dollar &operator+=(const Dollar &p1, const Dollar &p2);
```

This is wrong since I need to return a reference to a variable.

```
Dollar &operator+=(const Dollar &p1, const Dollar &p2)
{
    return p1+p2;
}
```

Comment: what is the confusion it looks like you are returning a reference

Comment: What is usually done is the other way round: you define `operator +` in terms of `operator +=`

Comment: Yes you're right! But what if both function should be friend function, as opposed to member function?

Comment: Its better to implement operators as friends only for binary oprators, it doesnt make any sense for unary operators. The reason for making operators as friends is that it makes your operator commutative. For example you making your own string class and you have operator + (concatenation). If you have made it as method, you wont be able to write 'abc' + mystring('cde')

Comment: @DzungNguyen, If `operator+=` needs to have access to private parts, make it a `friend` so that conversions can happen. `operator+` should be able to be a normal free function at that point and implemented with a single call to `operator+=`.

Comment: @EvgenyEltishev, `operator+=` *is* a binary operator.  However, as I'm sure you're aware, it's not one that you can usefully apply conversions to the LHS of (since it must take a non-const lvalue for its first argument).  That's why implementing it as a free/friend function doesn't give the same benefits as for `operator+` and other "symmetric-ish" binary operators.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Overloading operators as friend functions is better in order to allow conversions to apply to both the left and right side of the expression.  For example, `string`'s `operator+` is a friend so that I can write `"Hello " + string("World")` rather than only being able to write `string("Hello ") + "World"`.

However, this reasoning doesn't apply to mutators such as `operator+=`.  You have to take a non-const left argument, which precludes being able to use this operator on a temporary.  For this reason, it's recommended to implement non-mutating operators as `friend` (or otherwise free-) functions and mutators as member functions.  (In fact, `operator=` can only be overloaded as a member function.)

Answer (score 1):

You also need to modify the lvalue.

```
Dollar &operator+=(Dollar &p1, const Dollar &p2)
{
    p1=p1+p2;
    return p1;
}
```

Comment: This works but should contain a warning that defining `+` in terms of `+=` is more common because it's faster.

Answer (score 1):

The usual approach is to provide `+=` as a member function that modifies `*this` and to implement `+` as a free function that uses `+=`.

Comment: Side note: In C++11, if you're dealing with a literal type with `constexpr` operators, you can't implement forwarding in this direction.  In this situation, I usually end up implementing `+=` in terms of `+` (or implementing them independently), since a `constexpr operator+()` can't effectively call a mutator on one of its arguments.